# How to plot plot pairwise comparisons in ggplot2 (only sample statistics)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a bar graph that shows the means, the standard error of the means, and significant pairwise comparisons.

Something similar to this:

[image]

The data I have are only the means and standard error of the means.

```
group   x   mean   se of mean
a       1   3.650   0.092
a       2   4.232   0.081
a       3   3.653   0.068
a       4   3.871   0.13
b       1   3.984   0.07
b       2   4.150   0.073
b       3   4.058   0.054
b       4   4.010   0.132
c       1   2.915   0.1
c       2   3.475   0.1
c       3   3.246   0.086
c       4   3.069   0.16
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `ggsignif` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/README.html) to plot the significance for pairwise comparisons:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

# plot
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(
    comparisons = list(c("compact", "midsize"), c("minivan", "suv")),
    map_signif_level = TRUE,
    textsize = 6
  ) +
  ylim(NA, 48)
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(c(29, 29, 31, 30, 26, 26, 27, 26, 25, 28, :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I'm almost able to create the graph that I want, except that for the section: comparisons = list(c("compact", "midsize"), c("minivan", "suv")). I'm unable to refer to the specific contrasts I want, since I have groups within my x-axis. So for example, how would I refer to a contrast between group a, x=1 vs. group b, x=3?

Answer (score 0):

Using mpg data, I suppose you want to compare the **hwy** between class= minivan in year 1999 and class = suv in year 2008, which is similar to what you need.

You can add a new column to paste the two variable together, create something like minivan_1999, suv_2008. Using `ggpubr::stat_compare_means`, I demonstrate part of pairs for you:

```
mpg$detail <- paste(mpg$class, mpg$year, sep = "_")
my_comparison <- combn(unique(mpg$detail),2)
pairs <- list() # creating compairisons :list of pairs
for (i in 1:ncol(my_comparison)) {
  pairs[[i]] <- c(my_comparison[1,i], my_comparison[2,i])
}

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(x = detail, y = hwy, fill = detail)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()) + 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = pairs[1:4]) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

[image]